# Right-click Function Not working at runtime, because the supportive DLL is not present

Tags: powerbuilder

In my local machine where all the software's(.net, frameworks, so on) are present. I'm able run the application developed on Power Builder perfectly.

**My Problem:** But in the "Clean Environment(Fresh machine)" when i try to run the application the right click functionality is not working.

**here is the thing:** In my machine i can work perfectly. But on a clean machine right click functionality is working.

**Why?** Because the supportive DLL is missing in Application output Files.

**What do i need?** Name of the DLL which supports right click functionality in Power builder.

If you have doubts regarding my question, feel free to ask, I can furthur explain to you in detail if you need.

**Edit**: log obtained during right-click

```
Main Exception:
Exception Time: 2014-03-06 16:19:55.7773706
Process ID: 2188
AppDomain: urbis.exe Domain ID: 1
Managed Thread ID: 1
Current Thread State: Running
Method: Void remove_Click(System.EventHandler)
Exception Type: System.NullReferenceException
Exception Message: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   
   at System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem.remove_Click(EventHandler value)
   at Sybase.PowerBuilder.Win.WinOwnerdrawMenuItem.Sybase.PowerBuilder.Win.IPBWinMenu.remove_Click(EventHandler value)
   at Sybase.PowerBuilder.Win.PBMenu.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Sybase.PowerBuilder.PBPowerObject.PBDispose()
   at Sybase.PowerBuilder.PBSessionBase.DestroyObject(Object obj)
Exception Source: System.Windows.Forms
Exception StackTrace:    at System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem.remove_Click(EventHandler value)
   at Sybase.PowerBuilder.Win.WinOwnerdrawMenuItem.Sybase.PowerBuilder.Win.IPBWinMenu.remove_Click(EventHandler value)
   at Sybase.PowerBuilder.Win.PBMenu.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Sybase.PowerBuilder.PBPowerObject.PBDispose()
   at Sybase.PowerBuilder.PBSessionBase.DestroyObject(Object obj)
Exception Call Stack:    at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
```

Thank you

Comment: Where are you missing the "right click functionality": datawindow, windows, edit fields? What is "not working"? do you have any error message? Is it supposed to display something specific? Is the machine used to deploy the same system than your development machine?

Comment: Adding to Seki's questions, are these custom menus or the native RMB menus that come with the OS? There is no specific DLL for RMB menus, so unless this is the first time a menu is being instantiated, I'd expect you would have run into other problems before now if you couldn't instatiate menus. I'd try a PBDEBUG trace to see if that gave you any clues.

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave some basic info like: What version of PowerBuilder? Is it PowerBuilder.Net? Is it a Winform app deployed from PB Classic or a standard PowerBuilder app?

Comment: 1. in the "window". No error message.  eg: on right click "Expand All Level", on clicking on this, the contents inside should be expanded. Instead "No Action is taking place".                                             2. Power builder Classic 12.0 is being used.                               3. Thank you Seki, Terry, Roland Smith for your reply.

Comment: 4. "Important" : While debugging its working perfectly. In runtime its not working.   In detail if i have to say : Afetr deploying you will get "project output folder".I'm pasting that particular folder in a "clean machine(new OS where no software is installed)", And running the Application. Everything is working fine except right click functionality as explained above.

Comment: Does right clicking work in other apps on that machine? Could it have been turned off on that machine?

Comment: yes it works on other machines..  @Seki its "tree View DataWindow"..

Comment: I have added the exception log from [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22227317/error-log-while-calling-right-click-function-in-power-builder). do not open a new question to provide additional info, just edit your first question

Comment: I am not familiar with PB.Net but that log looks like a .Net exception  and stacktrace to me, not PB classic.

Comment: Please give a suggestion if you know about PB.Net.. After looking into log.. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

The PC where right-click is not working may be missing some .NET runtime DLL's from the GAC. According to the Sybase documentation:

```
The applications you create in PowerBuilder .NET automatically reference several .NET
assemblies that must be present in the global assembly cache (GAC) on the design time
and runtime computers. The PowerBuilder setup program installs the required assemblies
in the GAC of the design time computer, but they also must be deployed or installed in
the GAC of each runtime computer. The following list shows the Microsoft assemblies
(and their .NET Framework version numbers) that are installed with PowerBuilder and can
be redistributed to runtime computers with the PowerBuilder Runtime Packager:
• System.dll (v 2.0)
• PresentationCore.dll (v 3.0)
• PresentationFramework.dll (v 3.0)
• WindowsBase.dll (v 3.0)
• System.Xml.Linq.dll (v 3.5)
• Sybase.PowerBuilder.WPF.dll
• Sybase.PowerBuilder.Common.dll
• Sybase.PowerBuilder.Interop.dll
• Sybase.PowerBuilder.Core.dll
```

per page 5 of the:
http://download.sybase.com/beta/pb12ctp/Sybase_PB12_.NET_FeaturesGuide.pdf